# how to clear UILabel in TableViewCell when editing UITextField with code

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uilabel

I have one `UITextField` and I put `UILabel` that show me placeholder (I want change placeholder position so I add `UILabel` in my `UITableViewCell`).
any way!!!
I want when editing `UITextField` this means that I type any word in `UITextField` my label empty or remove from my cell and when touch any place except `UITextField` that `UILabel` that was my place holder add to cell again.
this is my cell code:

**TextFieldCell.h**

```
@interface TextFieldCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak,nonatomic) UITextField *Textfield;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *placeholder;

@end
```

**TextFieldCell.m**

```
@implementation TextFieldCell
@synthesize Textfield,placeholder;
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    Textfield = [self makeTextField];
    [self addSubview:Textfield];

    placeholder = [self PlaceHolderLabel];
    [self addSubview:placeholder];

}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
- (UITextField *)makeTextField
{
    CGRect TextFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,80);
    UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:TextFrame];
    textfield.delegate = self;
    textfield.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    textfield.placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mamal"];
    UIView *spacerleftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
    UIView *spacerrightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
    [textfield setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [textfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    textfield.leftView = spacerleftView;
    textfield.rightView = spacerrightView;


    return textfield;
}
- (UILabel *)PlaceHolderLabel{

    NSString *labelText = Textfield.placeholder;
    Textfield.placeholder = nil;
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,280,80);
    UILabel *placeholderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    [placeholderLabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [placeholderLabel setText:labelText];
    placeholderLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    return placeholderLabel;
}
- (UILabel *)clearPlaceHolderLabel{

    NSString *labelText = nil;
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,280,80);
    UILabel *placeholderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    [placeholderLabel setText:labelText];
    return placeholderLabel;
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //Keyboard becomes visible
    //perform actions.
    NSLog(@"start");
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"end");
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, why not use the placeholder property of UITextField instead of mocking about with a label? I think that will simply your code.

Comment: my friend I want change my placeholder position

Comment: What is the purpose of that exactly? From your code I see that the width of your textfield and label are the same, but 20px. And their positions are identical. That's why I'm wondering why you are not using the placeholder property instead.